# On eigenvalues of signed complete graphs

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, spectral-graph-theory

From [Akbari et al. -1](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1080/03081087.2017.1403548) as well as [Akbari et al. -2](https://sciendo.com/pdf/10.7151/dmgt.2276), we have that the eigenvalues of a signed complete graph $K_n$ with the negative edges forming an induced graph $H$ with order $k$ has the multiplicity of $(-1)$ as the eigenvalue equal to $m(-1)=n-k-1+null(H)$ where $null(H)$ represents the nullity of the adjacency matrix of $H$.

Now, suppose that I have $H$ to be four disjoint cliques of order $4$, with one vertex of each clique connected to a different new vertex. So, now can I say that the multiplicity of $(-1)$ as eigenvalue for the signed graph $K_{13}$ with $H$ as negative edge induced graph is greater than or equal to $4$? I think it is yes, but the switching of edges and induced graph formed by the negative edges is giving me some confusion. Any hints? Thanks beforehand.